# How to restart Ionic app in IOS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an ionic app for android and IOS. If any error occurred from server side or from client side the app gets restated. I am able to develop it for android using

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"
```

but for IOS I am not able to do this. Please let me know any solution for IOS.

I know there is `$state.go()` or `windows.reload` but this not worked for me because the some AppHub.On signals event are not initialize properly. 
Just only one solution will work for me just like android, but I am not able to do this same for IOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue

```
var initialHref = window.location.href;
navigator.splashscreen.show();
// Reload original app url (ie your index.html file)
window.location = initialHref;
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```